# django-haystack ordering alphabetically in order_by function

Tags: django, django-models, solr, sql-order-by, django-haystack

I have some problem with ordering in django-haystack >.<

the situation is:
i have Product model,
the product model have company_name attribute and this attribute also included in solr-haystack.

```
product_1.company name = "Cba ltd"
product_2.company_name = "Abc ltd"
product_3.company_name = "bac ltd"
product_4.company_name = "aac ltd"

sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).order_by("company_name")
```

when i searching and ordering by company name, the result is [product_2, product_1, product_4, product_3]

the system ordering uppercase first then after uppercase finish, will continue to lowercase.

how to make it only alphabetic without checking uppercase or lowercase?
the result supposed to be [product_4, product_2, product_3, product_1]

thank you for helping me in this situation.

cheers,

Answer (score 3):

You can use extra and pass 'company_name' to lower()

This would look something like:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).order_by("company_name").extra(select={'company_name': 'lower(company_name)'}).order_by('company_name')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to order by a multivalue field, and an analyzed string is a multivalue field.

So create a non-analyzed field with the same data used for sorting:

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    company_name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='company_name')
    company_name_raw = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name', indexed=False)

sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).order_by('company_name_raw')
```

See the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/multi-fields.html) for more info.